# Diffusion profile for localised release

Tags: diffusion

I am trying to solve the 1-D diffusion equation in a tube of finite length that extends from $-L\leq x \leq L$. I have assumed that the radius is much smaller than the length of the tube so that we can neglect variations in the radial direction. Suppose I inject some amount of a substance at $t = 0$ such that the concentration at $x = 0$ is $\text{5000 ppm}$. I am having some trouble formulating the boundary conditions and initial conditions. Here's what I have thought of so far-

$\text{I.C: @ } t=0$ $$C = 5000\delta(x)$$
$\text{B.C: @ } x = 0$ $$\frac{\partial C}{\partial x} = 0 \hspace{10pt} \text{[assuming symmetry about x = 0]}$$

I am not too sure about the 2nd boundary condition. Would it be right to take $\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}$ at $x = L$ if I take an impermeable boundary? The initial condition is also something I am not too sure of since I thought of the Dirac-Delta function has having value $\infty$ at $x = 0$ and $0$ everywhere else. In some places it is defined as being equal to $1$ and $0$ respectively. If the former is true then multiplying it by 5000 doesn't make much sense. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial condition is correct: the density is infinite, but the integral (the total amount) is finite.

The boundary condition must be imposed at $x=\pm L$: it is the flux that is equal to zero.

Comment: So if I only consider diffusive flux while neglecting any sort of convection, I would get $\frac{\partial C}{\partial x} = 0$ at $x = \pm L$. Since it is symmetric I only need to consider one of these boundaries.
I am still confused about the initial condition though. I do not have the total amount that was injected, just the concentration at $t = 0$. Not sure what the integral would yield.

Comment: The concentration $C(x,t)$ is like the density $\rho(x,t)$. The integral gives you the total amount (the mass M, for example, or the total number of particles).