# Solution of the 1D diffusion equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffusion

This equation is related to a similar question I have asked before here-[Diffusion profile for localised release](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566534/diffusion-profile-for-localised-release).
I am trying to solve this equation numerically in MATLAB. I have approximated the density of the substance 'A' by a normal distribution at $t=0$ so that I don't have to deal with the Delta function. Suppose I have a cylindrical tank with cross-sectional area of $\text{1m}^2$ and it extends from $-5\text{m} \leq x \leq 5\text{m}$. The diffusion coefficient is $2.25\times10^{-9}$ m^2/sec. At $(t=0, x=0)$, I introduce 2.85 kg of A. The density distribution at t = 0 is then given by-$$\rho(0,x)=\frac{2.85}{0.001\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(\frac{-x^2}{2\times(0.001)^2})\hspace{10pt} \text{[kg/m3]}$$

The integral of the above function would then give me the total mass of A at t=0 which is 2.85 kg. The boundary conditions are as follows-
at $x=0$: $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = 0 \hspace{5pt} \text{[assuming symmetry about x = 0]}$$
and the other BC at $x = 5$: $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = 0 \hspace{5pt} \text{[assuming zero flux]}$$

At $t=\infty$, I expected the density profile to be constant throughout the tank at 2.85/10 = 0.285 kgm-3. Instead, the numerical solution gives me a value of 11.35 kgm-3 which is exactly 1/100 of the value of density at t=0, x=0 $[\rho(0,0)]$. Where am I going wrong here?

**EDIT:**I played around with the stepsizes of the length and the standard deviation and got the correct result. A value of $\sigma = 0.01$ and $\Delta x=0.01$ did return the 0.285 I expected. I think the earlier step-size of 0.1 was too big to take into account the normal distribution. Would love some more insight on this.

Comment: I'm really not sure why you want to use MATLAB here. This is the most basic diffusion problem there is: homogeneous boundary conditions and symmetric initial condition. And it's a quasi-$\text{1D}$ problem to boot!

Comment: I am doing this exercise as part of a numerical analysis course. I did find some material wherein a general result of the same problem has been given but I wanted to check if a numerical procedure would yield the same solution. Evidently, the process has been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is more of a computational error here, because your distribution is so narrow in comparison with your tank, probably the discretization is not as dense to consider the distribution before it decays to zero, leaving you with a single point of mass $\rho(0,0)$ that when distributed evenly, gives you the result you mention. Maybe try with a smaller grid, try to have a grid of $\sigma / 2$ at most if not smaller and see if that fix the issue

Comment: Yup. That sorted things out. Thanks!